# Disconnect shared network folder on server side?

Tags: windows-xp, network-share, net

Normally I use the following command to make a shared network folder connection:

```
net use * \\remotebox\sharedfolder /user:userid pwd
```

This command is used on the the client side.  Is there any similar command tool on the remote side to see who have connections and disconnect the connection?

The reason I ask this question is that today I have one case: the connection on the client side (Windows XP) is lost, but it seems that the server side (Windows XP as well) does not get notification about the connection lost. The client box was reboot and still could make a connection again. I had to reboot the remote PC to get the problem resolved.

Then I think that I need to find out a way on the server side (folder to be shared) to know what PCs have connection and to reset the connection. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to prevent the client machines from mapping to the server altogether?

Comment: No, just disclose the connection session. It is a very interesting topic. By using command "net session ... /delete" as suggested by @ynguldyn, the session can be deleted, but not the mapping. What I wanted to do is close the hanging session so that client use can do the remap again.

Answer (score 2):

To see who's connected:

```
net session
```

To end a connection:

```
net session \\computername /delete
```

Comment: I tried this command. It seems that the session can be deleted, but the client side can still run dir command to access to the shared network driver. Not sure this dir command will rebuild the connection again?

Answer (score 0):

The auto-reconnection feature at the client may be what you are running up against. It will cache the login and attempt to reconnect, if it detects that a resource is no longer available.

If you are trying to disconnect all active remote sessions on the server, then stopping the "Server" services is more effective, but it is an "all or nothing" option.